# Flutter TextInputAction.done not showing checkmark button

Tags: android, flutter, dart, textformfield, swift-keyboard

I have this **TextFormField** in a Stateful widget

```
TextFormField(
                    decoration: InputDecoration(labelText: "Image URL"),
                    keyboardType: TextInputType.url,
                    textInputAction: TextInputAction.done,
                  )
```

The expected behavior is to see a *checkmark* button (instead of *newline* button) in my swiftkey keyboard on my Android device; but nothing has changed on the keyboard.
I have tried another **TextInputActions** like **Search** and **Send** they appear properly.

Comment: What is your `flutter doctor -v`?

Comment: You want to change a character on the keyboard or on the UI?

Comment: @Ferdinand on a keyboard, instead of newline button it should appear a check mark button

Comment: Perhaps you could try creating an IconButton besides the TextField that appears when the input has been validated

Answer (score 1):

Even flutter is a great platform, there are still some missing points need to be improved. So in your case most probably;

`keyboardType` is affecting the done button to not show up. So if you simply change your `keyboardType` to `TextInputType.text` your keyboard will start showing checkmark icon.

Comment: Thanks for your reply but I have changed the code as you said but no check mark appeared!